# MUI pseudo-class last-of-type

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get the the last `<NotificationContainer>` component to have a margin of 100px. My markup here doesn't work. I'm building using MUI5.

```
const Container = styled('div')(() => ({
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  border: `1px solid`,
  padding: '20px'
}));

const NotificationContainer = styled('div')(() => ({
  alignItems: 'center',
  border: `1px solid`,
  display: 'flex',
  marginBottom: '10px',
  "& :last-of-type": {
    marginBottom: "100px"
  }
}));

export const Page: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <NotificationContainer>
        Applicant: Test
      </NotificationContainer>

      <NotificationContainer>
        Test 2
      </NotificationContainer>

      <NotificationContainer>
        Test 3
      </NotificationContainer>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try removing the space: `"&:last-of-type"`

Comment: Thank you. That's it. If you want to make it an answer I will upvote.

Comment: Done! Glad that helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to remove the space: `"&:last-of-type"`

That's the usual syntax for selectors like this in Material :)